# Radius Around User's Curren Location Swift iOS 9

Tags: swift, xcode7.3

I want to put a 100 mile radius around User's Current location. I have successfully gotten the user's location. I have added a radius around the coordinates. (Meaning if the user location changes, the radius will stay and that's not what I want.) The Radius should go everywhere the User's Location goes.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdUjD.png)

Answer (score 1):

Change the location of the circle when the location of the user changes. You can observe the user's location by using the `CLLocationManagerDelegate`.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation)
{
    //update location of circle, newLocation.coordinate
    //something like this:
    circle = MKCircle(centerCoordinate: newLocation.coordinate, radius: 160934 as CLLocationDistance)
}
```

You need to declare the `var circle:MKCircle` outside of the `viewDidLoad` scope.